# How can I put date alwaays right bottom in chat screen?

Tags: react-native, whatsapp

How can I place the date time always in the right bottom like in the picture ?

As you can see in whatsapp, date of the message always placed in right bottom corner even the message is single line one or multi line.

What kind a setup do I need for this or can I achieve this result just with styling?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions, Put these styles into your root view

`The first Solution`

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Text>Your message</Text>
    <Text style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0}}>Your Date</Text>
</View
```

`Second Solution`

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <Text>Your message</Text>
    <Text>Your Date</Text>
<?View>
```

Comment: this is not a right solution . but thank you i tried it